# In Excel, how do I create a table and chart showing number of tasks for a given day

Tags: excel, countif

A table contains a schedule of tasks; each task has a start-date and end-date.  [image: Task Table]

In a separate table, I want count the number of active tasks in a given day based on the start-date being Greater-than-or-equal-to the row date; and the end-date being Less-than-or-equal-to the row date. [image: Count of Active Tasks Table]

Sounds like a `COUNTIFS` function; so I used the following formula: `=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$174,">="&J2,$E$2:$E$174,"<="&J2)`.

The problem is that the results are not correct...or, at least they do not seem correct upon visual inspection.  I also tried with named ranges and that failed as well.

So, is the formula wrong or am I using the wrong approach?

Comment: How did you arrive to the Expected CT ? Are you using the '=' in the formulae correctly ?

Comment: @Pratham DavidN had the fix; the equal was correct it was just bad use of GT and LT!

Comment: Can someone explain why this was voted to be closed? Can I see the reasoning? I felt this was a legit question (albeit a simple one) with good detail on what I tried and what hadn't worked; I even searched SO first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right, but your `COUNTIF` logical operators are backwards.

It should be `=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$174,"<="&J2,$E$2:$E$174,">="&J2)`.

Your start date should be *less* than the target date, and the end date should be *more* than the target date.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidN, that was the issue.  I will now retake remedial Excel class as penance.